# RPA Blueprism input collection in process studio action stage

Tags: blueprism

Trying to parameterize a hotel booking page where we need to enter check in, check out details etc. I created a page in object studio with various action/navigation stages for that web page. Now I need to call that object in process and loop it with input collection. When I am calling that object studio page in process studio action stage, I can select my object and action from dropdown, but under inputs tab not getting any row to drag and drop the input collection that I have created, how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you should go take Blue Prism tutorial on their homepage, as this very basic, it's how to call another process/Business object.

Short description:

1. Create a process which is your main.
2. Create your functionality in a Business object.
3. From your process you will pull in an 'Action' block and find your
   business object in the drop down.
4. When it comes to input/output. Click on Start/End
   to create the Input/Output you need.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I think I am not able to put my question properly or you have not read my previous comment to RAFEL.  I have created object, Process and action in process to call that object. I have selected that object in the action stage drop down and on the inputs tab I am expecting a blank row with fields (Name, Data type and Value), I am not getting that blank row. I have seen the same in a youtube video for some instructor but not getting it. There should be a screenshot sharing option on this website, it'll become so easy to make question understand.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you unless you show me your start step in BO and action input/output.

Comment: how should I show it ? any way to send screenshot ? any email id?

Comment: Just to add to it, If I create an object page with single web page input field and call it in process studio action stage, it does work and I can drag input collection in the desired row, but only when I am having multiple input fields in one object studio page, I am not getting the input row in process studio action stage to drag input collection.  and at the loop start stage I have already defined the collection to be used, but we need to define the exact column value in each action stage also, thats where the issue is coming

Comment: I can send you an email with exact screenshots, I am stuck from the past 10 days and nobody is able to help anywhere, let me know if you can share your email id pls

Comment: splittergal@gmail.com - Please send screen shots and explanation, I will also change my answer when I know more about your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but shouldn't you input your data in `START` step in proces studio?

So, in `START` step in proces studio you input data and then(whit that input) you go into actions from your object.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nope, from start we first create excel instance, open workbook and get to collection to load excel data in our collection, now when the loop starts we have to pass that loaded collection into action stage, but on double clicking the action stage you select your business object and action from dropdown, now you should get a row in the inputs tab to drag and drop your collection. but I am not getting that row, did that clarify my question ? Not sure how to add a screenshot here

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you place your data items/collections which ever is output in run time object in END stage, and make sure you uncheck hide from process box.
2. In process you will be able to find necessary output from object and will involve in your rest action

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide input parameters in the Start properties of your Object. Inputs to a page in Object Studio provide the means for a Process to supply data to the Business Object. 
Essentially, the Business Object is saying to the Process, “What check in, check out details etc do you want me to work with?”. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it is resolved! 
When you create an Object and go to Application Modeller, make sure you choose "Browser Based Application" instead of Windows Based Application. I had selected Windows based applocation and it was not showing up in the Process Studio. I hope this